# ssis for each loop "Foreach File Enumerator" file appears twice

Tags: for-loop, ssis, file-rename

am upgrading an ssis package that loads data from CSV files.

first step in process - rename *.CSV to *_YYYYMM.csv
this has been working fine (for 32 files)
now am updating to load in data from an extra 13 files

when looping around, one of the new extra CSV files appears in the FOR EACH file list twice - and so gets renamed to *_201607_201607.CSV

could put the rename into a script task - but want to know why one of the 45 files is getting renamed twice ???

am running sql2012

Comment: Is this just a standard Foreach (file) Loop Container with a File System task inside of it or is there something special in here?

Comment: is just a standard container with FileSystem task inside it.
have tried several things - renaming the file from ReorientationStrategies.csv to Reorientations.csv solved the problem but wonder why it occurred.
and also why it didn't occur on any other files (including ReorientationStrategiesOther.csv) ??

Comment: Could you better specify the flow? In order to better understand the components are you using.